# Symbolic matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm dealing with infinite dimensional matrices $M$, who's elements $M_{nm}$ can be expressed as a sum of terms with kronecker deltas $a_{nk}\delta_{n+k,m}$, with some coefficient $a_{nk}$ for each kronecker delta. I'd like to be able to use Mathematica to symbolically do matrix multiplication of two such matrices, and have the output give me each coefficient $a_{nk}$ of the resultant matrix as a function of $n$ and $k$. Is such a thing possible?

**Edit:** My apologies, I wasn't sure of the policy in this forum on including code. I tried  while ago without any success, and didn't save it. I will try again and show you what my ideas were. In the meantime, I will give you a better idea for what output I am looking for. In general, and infinite dimensional matrix can be written in the form

$$M_{nm}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{nk}\delta_{n+k,m}$$
Matrix multiplication of two matrices $A$ and $B$ would go like
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}A_{nj}B_{jm}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{nk}b_{jl}\delta_{n+k,j}\delta_{j+l,m}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{nk}b_{m-l,l}\delta_{n+k+l,m}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{nk}\delta_{n+k,m}$$
Where $$c_{nk}=\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n,\frac{k+l}{2}}b_{n+\frac{k+l}{2},\frac{k-l}{2}}$$
There may be a different way to simplify this expression, but this is the quantity I would like as an output as a function of $n$ and $k$. Typically the sum over $k$ in the expression for $M_{nm}$ would be finite.

Comment: Please include in your question the code you have tried and sample terms of your matrices.

Comment: Maybe you can formulate the matrix multiplication as a sum and show in your post what simplification you desire.